# DataFrame.sum returns Series and not a number

Tags: python, pandas

My basic task is to take vector `x=[x1,x2,x3,x4]` (which in my case is presented by a row of a Pandas dataframe, lets say a row with an index = 1), multiply it by scalar `k` and to sum up the results -> `x1*k + x2*k + x3*k + x4*k`.

I did not find a function that would do it in one step (Is there such a function/operation?), so i do it in two steps. First i multiply my vector `x` by scalar `k`, and then i sum up the results:

```
x_by_k = my_df.loc[[1]]*k
sum = x_by_k.sum(axis=1)
```

One of the problems i have here is that the resulting `sum` is of `Series` type, although effectively it is a number.

Is there a way to perform this sum operation with a number as an output?

Can i do the above described in one step?

Comment: Don't name a variable the same name as a built-in function, e.g.. `sum`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC select row in `df` by [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html), then [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html) and multiple by `k`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9]})

print (df)
   A  B  C
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9

k = 2
sum = df.ix[1].sum()* k
print (sum)
30
```

Comment: wrap it with a pretty bow: `sum_row_mul_k = lambda df, row, k: df.ix[row].sum() * k`

Comment: No.  `iloc` vs `ix` doesn't matter.  It was the `.sum()` that turned it into a number.

Comment: @piRSquared But i tried doing this: my_df.X.loc[[1]].T.sum() (which is effectively what is done in the answer) - and it still returned Series and not a number

Comment: .. and the reason for that ( i guess) is that loc - gives you a dataframe and ix - gives you series

Comment: @Dennis `my_df` is a dataframe (2-d).  `my_df.X` is a column in that dataframe and is of type `pd.Series` (1-d).  But then you select an element in that series with `my_df.X.loc[[1]]`.  That extra `[]` in the `loc` selector ensured the dimensionality stayed (1-d) instead of (0-d) as you wanted.  You should have just done `my_df.X.loc[1]`

Comment: @piRSquared Ha, although i messed up naming in the previous comment, making it all very confusing :) you are right - second level of [] was causing an error, thank you ! :)